# Playing a MPMediaItem video closes itself

Tags: objective-c, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmediaitem

I am experimenting with writing an app that allows the user to play videos from their iTunes library from the app itself (it will be a small part of a larger app).

I am currently searching and populating a table with TV programs data from iTunes. This is working fine.

However, when I tap the cell and attempt to play the video associated with it, the media player opens, and immediately closes itself.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"touch!");

    MPMediaItem *v = [videos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSURL *url = [v valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];

    MPMoviePlayerViewController *p = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
    [self presentViewController:p animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

It seemed to work okay when I wasn't filtering to only TV shows though.

Any ideas?